# Exclude a content source from Search result

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, search-scope, enterprise-search

We have created a content source and we would like it to be excluded from the SharePoint search results.

I know one way would be to use Query Rules and exclude the content sources using following query

```
{searchTerms} -ContentSource:Private
```

However I am assuming that it must be pulling all the search results initially and trimming them based on the Query,  which would have some performance impact.

Do we have any other way of achieving this other then Query Rules or Crawl Rules?

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK only OOTB way is using the result source in [SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683115.aspx)

or search scopes in [SharePoint 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792872%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

a guide...http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2013/04/limiting-search-results-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: thanks Waqas,  do we have any option if we decide to write something custom? e.g. Security Trimmer?

Answer (score 0):

There are two other approaches to exclude or remove a content from SharePoint search results:

1. Search Result Removal Option
2. Crawl Log option.

For detailed explanation and steps, you may refer this article:
http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Remove-result-from-Search-Results-in-SharePoint-2010

Comment: Thanks for Sharing this,  our main concern is about the performance. Removing the content source from Crawl Log will take the search results for all future crawls,  we want the search to crawl the content sources,  we would like to remove this content sources from default search results.